# Email sending fails with private email domain: C# code

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, email

In my winforms application I am Using the following function to send emails.

```
    public void sendEmailWithHotmail(string emailFrom, string emailPwd, string emailTo, string smtpHost, int smtpPort, string msg)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom, "Test EMail");
        mail.To.Add(emailTo);
        mail.Subject = "Hi";
        mail.Body = msg;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, emailPwd);
        SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, smtpPort);
        mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
        mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        mailClient.Credentials = mailAuthentication;
        mailClient.Timeout = 20000;
        mailClient.Send(mail);            
    }
```

This code works really fine with gmail, Hotmail and yahoo without any problem.
(with yahoo: `mailClient.EnableSsl = false;` and with gmail/hotmail: `mailClient.EnableSsl = true;`)

```
Gmail   -> smtp port: smtp.gmail.com,   smtp Port: 587
Hotmail -> smtp port: smtp.live.com,   smtp Port: 25
Yahoo   -> smtp port: smtp.mail.yahoo.com,   smtp Port: 25
```

The problem I have is, it continually get an exception saying `Smtp Exception : Failure sending mail` with my private email domain.. `myemailId@privatedomain.com`
I have given the correct smtp Host and Port number

Does anyone have any idea, why this happens so..?? Thanks inadvance.

Comment: @leppie I think its a typo for `personal`

Comment: Sorry it should be private domain

Answer (score 0):

Your mail provider probably doesnt allow relay. THis means you can only send email from the address you are logged in with

Comment: Hi Luke, I have set my email with MS Outlook. I can Send emails manually with outlook for any email Address without any restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you maybe tried to use RepltToList?

```
     msg.ReplyToList.Add(replyTo);
```

I Had some problems sending mail without this.

Answer (score 0):

I would figure it's a configuration issue of the private mail server. maybe even a stupid thing like enabling SMTP support server side. try looking into the private mail server configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Is your domain linked with google apps?

I was also facing a similar problem once.One of my sub-domain was pointing to google apps mail(the free version/non enterprise version) and I was unable to send mails using PHP.

Let me know.

Comment: Hi LordKakarot, I am not sure what exactly mean by whether the domain is linked with google apps. Can you please expliain a bit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this configuration in your app.confg:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="abc@somedomain.com">
        <network host="somesmtpserver" port="25" userName="name" password="pass" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
 </system.net>
```